# consulta de posicionamiento de imagenes en css

Tags: html, css, html5, imagen

Estoy practicando el posicionamiento de imágenes en css pero me surgió un problema,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código:

```
body {       
  background:
    url(decoration.png) left top no-repeat,
    url(ribbon.png) right top no-repeat,
    url(old_paper.jpg); 
}
```

Cuando trato de que el listón rojo este en la parte inferior derecha (`right bottom`) este desaparece

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código:

```
body {
  background:
    url(decoration.png) left top no-repeat,
    url(ribbon.png) right bottom no-repeat,
    url(old_paper.jpg); 
}
```

¿Por qué pasa esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le estaría faltando el alto al body

```css
body {
  background: 
  url(https://picsum.photos/120/?image=15) right bottom no-repeat,
  url(https://picsum.photos/120/?image=10) left top no-repeat,
  url(https://picsum.photos/1200/?image=20);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```